# Send ics File from Twilio for Whatsapp REST API

Tags: rest, api, twilio, whatsapp

I need to send a Calendar file (ICS) from the REST Api but i can`t.

Nevertheless, I could send a jpg file. In [this](https://www.twilio.com/blog/whatsapp-media-support)  article Twilio staff announced that users can send 
 ***images and videos, but also PDFs, text files, and audio files using the Twilio API for WhatsApp.***

This is my call with JPG file that attach the media in a whatsapp message OK:

```
curl -X POST \
https://api.twilio.com/2010-04-01/Accounts/ACYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYY/Messages.json \
-H 'authorization: Basic 
XXXXXXXXXXXXX' \
-H 'cache-control: no-cache' \
-H 'content-type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded' \
-H 'postman-token: 58fa6aca-3b92-66d4-f675-9906bed37302' \
-d 'To=whatsapp%3A%2BXXXXXXXX&From=whatsapp%3A%2BYYYYYYY&Body=Hola%20probando2&MediaUrl=https%3A%2F%2Flh4.googleusercontent.com%2F-nbafRpNzZAc%2FWjHLp8y3NOI%2FAAAAAAAAAAA%2Fc8CSoPlcgcAazvZFKSU3uYxwo3HZ7FVewCOQCEAE%2Fs128-c-k%2Fphoto.jpg%0A'
```

When i substitute MediaUrl path with a txt file path or ics file, the message wasn't attach the file:

for example something like this:

```
curl -X POST \
https://api.twilio.com/2010-04-01/Accounts/ACYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYY/Messages.json \
-H 'authorization: Basic 
XXXXXXXXXXXXX' \
-H 'cache-control: no-cache' \
-H 'content-type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded' \
-H 'postman-token: 58fa6aca-3b92-66d4-f675-9906bed37302' \
-d 'To=whatsapp%3A%2BXXXXXXXX&From=whatsapp%3A%2BYYYYYYY&Body=Hola%20probando2&MediaUrl=https:%2F%2Faaa.bbb.com%2Fccc%2Fcalendar.ics%0A'
```

Answer (score 1):

Below is a list of supported file types, I don't see the files you are trying to send as supported types for the underlying [WhatsApp Business API](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/whatsapp/api/media/).

[Sending and Receiving Media with WhatsApp Messaging on Twilio (Beta)](https://support.twilio.com/hc/en-us/articles/360017961894-Sending-and-Receiving-Media-with-WhatsApp-Messaging-on-Twilio-Beta-)

Comment: in this line: 
 `To=whatsapp%3A%2BXXXXXXXX&From=whatsapp%3A%2BYYYYYYY&Body=Hola%20probando2&MediaUrl=https:%2F%2Faaa.bbb.com%2Fccc%2Fcalendar.ics%0A' `  In the log sms i see the file uploaded but twilio can't send me the file. maybe txt files not supported. Really? It's incredible!

Comment: Currently, vcf is not a supported media format but may be in the future.

Comment: WhatsApp integration now supports sending vcard/vcf files - https://www.twilio.com/changelog/contact-card-support-whatsapp-vcard

Comment: Somewhere along the line I mixed up .ics with .vcf :( Sorry, I know you asked about .ics which is a Calendar file, not a contact information card.